# extracting days between a dataframe date and today

Tags: datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a date in a dataframe and I would like to create another dataframe column that has the number of days between this date (option expiration) and today.  The date looks like this:

```
df2.expiration.head(1)

0    05/29/15
Name: expiration, dtype: object
```

i tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def compare_dates(date):
    date_format = '%m/%d/%YY'
    current_date = datetime.strptime(date, date_format)  
    today = datetime.today()
    diff = current_date - today
    return diff.days

df2['days_since'] = df2['expiration'].apply(compare_dates)
```

but I get a long error message with the final line of:

```
ValueError: time data '05/29/15' does not match format 'mm/dd/YY'
```

Thank you once again !
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (note lower case 'y'):

```
date_format = '%m/%d/%y'
```

`%Y` is for a four digit year, and `%YY` would be for a four digit year ending in 'Y', e.g. '2015Y'.

```
s = '05/29/15'
>>> dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%y').date()
datetime.date(2015, 5, 29)
```

Comment: nope,   same thing happened                                                                                                     ValueError: time data '05/29/15' does not match format '%m/%d/%yy'

Comment: Sorry. Try again noting the expanded %mm and %dd for two digit months and days, respectively.  The full list can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Comment: I had tried that before I posted, tried again with lower yy to make sure and still same error: ValueError: time data '05/29/15' does not match format '%mm/%dd/%yy'

Comment: saying your sorry for helping sounds odd :-)  it worked, thank you